# How do I compute derivative of $\int_0^xe^{-t^{2}}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I compute derivative of $$\int_0^xe^{-t^{2}}dt $$ I tried by solving it and then thought of taking derivative. My friend has told me that this can be done by both solving and not solving. I would like to see both.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Comment: @TaylorTed: as written, your quantity does not really make sense: there is a conflict of notation between the upper bound of the integral ($x$) and the dummy integration variable. I assume you refer to the function $f$ defined as $f(x) = \int_0^x e^{-t^2}dt$, whose derivative is then $e^{-x^2}$ (according to the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus)?

Comment: The derivative with respect to what variable? Are you sure that you want $x$ both as the upper limit, but also as the variable of integration?

Comment: @ClementC. my friend told me derivative is $(1-2x)e^{-x^{2}}$

Comment: @TaylorTed For *which* function? As written above, as of now the expression you wrote is not well-defined ($x$ is used both as upper bound of the integral and integration variable; it cannot)

Comment: @TaylorTed If you meant $\int_0^x e^{-t^2} dt$, then that is not correct. That is the sort of error that is common when you use the same variable for the integration as for the upper limit (which you should never do, for this reason and because it just isn't even sensibly defined). Also, it is not possible to do this by computing the antiderivative and then taking the derivative of the result, because the antiderivative is not an elementary function.

Comment: @ClementC. edited question.it was dt i meant not dx

Comment: @TaylorTed Then the derivative is $e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: This is a direct application of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to solve the actual integral:

Use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

say $\int f(t) dt= g(t)$ then $\int^x_0 f(t) dt= g(x)-g(0)$

$\frac{d}{dx} \int^x_0 f(t) dt=\frac{d}{dx} [g(x)-g(0)]=g'(x)=f(x)$
Since $g(0)$ is just a constant

So $\int^x_0 e^{-t^2}= e^{-x^2}$

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can write the integral as $\int_0^xe^{-{t^2}}dt$ for convenience, so we have $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x f(t)dt=f(x)$$ Then the answer is  $ e^{-{x^2}}.$

Comment: @Clement I kindly thanks you.

Comment: Excuse me it was my mistake I edit it.